# Joomla! 3.0: core module edition not working

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm trying to edit the default core module named mod_weblinks to change how the list of weblinks within a category is shown.

The problem comes when I change the default.php file in modules/mod_weblinks/tmpl/ and I get no results when hit f5.

I also tried to copy and odify this file in template/my_template/html/mod_weblinks/ but same result.

I uninstalled and installed this module from joomla! control admin panel.

Any suggestion?

TIA

Comment: It could be due to a caching issue. Try clearing you browser's cache.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it, the problem is that I was modifying a module but using a component so I have change the code of the component (which is a bit more complex)